# MATLAB not throwing OutOfMemoryExceptions or Maximum variable size errors

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

In a previous version of MATLAB (7.6), I used to get OutOfMemoryErrors that I thought were kind of annoying.  But since I upgraded to 7.11, for some reason it's not throwing the errors anymore.

This means that when I accidentally try to make a variable that's way too large, the MATLAB shell will try to create the variable and bring my machine to a halt.

I'd really like to have these errors get thrown, so that I can exit out gracefully or debug my code, but I can't find the solution anywhere.

Possibly useful details:
I'm using OSX 10.5 on a 64-bit machine, with 4GB of RAM.

In MATLAB 7.6:

```
$ rand(50000);
??? Error using ==> rand
Maximum variable size allowed by the program is exceeded.
```

In MATLAB 7.11:

```
$ rand(50000);
(hang)
```

Comment: Good question. Hubris always seems to catch me and I end up creating huge matrices that crash matlab.

Comment: 7.6-->7.11 seems to be a downgrade not an upgrade?

Comment: @albanx: 6->11 is an upgrade. It's not 7.1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between version 7.6 and 7.11 the Macintosh version of MATLAB switched from a 32-bit application to a 64-bit application. So now instead of running out of address space MATLAB thrashes.

Comment: This seems like the most likely answer.  I don't suppose there's a way to artificially suppress the amount of address space in MATLAB?

Comment: Not in MATLAB (usually people want more address space!) and unfortunately it looks like Mac OS X doesn't support the limit/ulimit mechanism to limit available memory either.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab doesn't hang. It's just paging, which takes forever. Try assigning a large array, open the Activity Monitor, and see the 'Virtual Memory' grow and grow.

If you reduce the page file size on your system, you can avoid that issue.